# How is Boost able to achieve such syntax?

Tags: c++, boost

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html

```
// Declare the supported options.
.............................................
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;
```

Is it through operator overloading?

If yes, which operator was overloaded here?

Can you mimic this syntax using a simple non-Boost example program?

Comment: Looks like the function call operator, each call returns the same object, which has the `operator()` overloaded to add a new option.

Comment: @BoBTFish Since that's pretty much a complete answer, you could have posted it as such :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is self-explanatory

```
#include <iostream>

class funky_counter
{
public:
    funky_counter() : value_(0) {}

public:
    funky_counter & increment(int value)
    {
        value_ += value;
        return *this;
    }

public:
    funky_counter & operator()(int value)
    {
        return this->increment(value);
    }

public:
    int get_value() 
    { 
        return value_; 
    }

private:
    int value_;
};

int main(void)
{
    funky_counter counter;

    counter.increment(2) (5) (7);

    std::cout <<  counter.get_value() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`desc.add_options()` returns an object with an overloaded `operator()`. This means that the object can be called as if it was a function.

To be more specific, `options_descriptions::add_options()` returns a `options_description_easy_init` object. This object has an `operator()`, which returns a reference to `*this`: any invocation of the `operator()` returns a reference to the `options_description_easy_init` object itself, so it can be called again.

You can find the source code for both `options_descriptions` and `options_description_easy_init` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp).

To replicate this yourself, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class callable {
public:
    class callable &operator()(const std::string &s) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

callable make_printer() {
    return callable();
}

int main() {
    make_printer()("Hello, World!")("Also prints a second line");
    return 0;
}
```